# firefox addon change response code

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have an extension that is checking response in `http-on-examine-response` listener. In the listener it is possible change the headers via [httpChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIHttpChannel), and via [nsITraceableChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/NsITraceableChannel) we can change response content.

But how to change response code (for example from 407 to 200) in the `http-on-examine-response` listener?

Some code:

```
const { Ci, Cu, Cc, Cr } = require('chrome');

Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

var observer = {
  observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    if (aTopic == 'http-on-examine-response') {
        console.log('we are in observer http-on-examine-response');
        var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
        if(httpChannel.responseStatus == 407){
            httpChannel.responseStatus = 200; // <-- this is not working
        }
    }

  }
};

Services.obs.addObserver(observer, 'http-on-examine-response', false);


exports.onUnload = function (aData, aReason) {
  Services.obs.removeObserver(observer, 'http-on-examine-response');
};
```

Comment: You have to use `http-on-modify-response`

Comment: 1) I fix my mistake, there must be `http-on-examine-response` 2) There is no such event like `http-on-modify-response` in This code: http://pastebin.com/nwFv2RgZ this event is not triggered.

Comment: Oh my mistake, it is `http-on-examine-response`, try that please. See the docs here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests

Comment: No, there is no mathod for changing responce code. That [traceable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/NsITraceableChannel) reader work only with responce body(avrything after first "\r\n\r\n" in responce), while responce code is in a first line of it.

Comment: Can yo not use `setResponseHeader` to set this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIHttpChannel#setResponseHeader%28%29

Comment: No. Responce headers are evrything from second line to first '\r\n\r\n'. But I need to change the first line: http://pastebin.com/q56eYRTN (in the first line you can see 200 - and this is a responce code)

Comment: `setStatusLine` looks interesting, check this out - https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?q=responsestatus&redirect=false&case=false

Comment: This is method of instance nsIHttpResponse type. How I can get binded nsIHttpResponse object in `http-on-examine-response` handler and change it?

Comment: And even more, the wrapper for this objec is in [httpd.js](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/services/sync/tps/extensions/mozmill/resource/stdlib/httpd.js) (search for `function Response(connection)`), so this is unrelated.

Comment: It would be helpful to have your current code so we do not have to write everything around it in order to test possible solutions. In other words, please make it easier for us to try to help you. Currently, we have to put in quite a bit of work (work that you appear to have already done) just to get to the point of being able to start trying solutions.